# Problems with legend resizing with grid.arrange and ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a multi-panel plot with `ggplot2` (using `grid.extra` and `egg` packages). Two of the plots are box plots and the third uses `geom_count`. Like:

```
f <- ggplot(mpg, aes(drv, cty)) + geom_boxplot()

f2 <- ggplot(mpg, aes(drv, hwy)) + geom_boxplot()

f3 <- ggplot(mpg, aes(drv, class)) + 
      geom_count() + scale_size_area(max_size = 15)
```

When I try to arrange them using:

```
b <- grid.arrange(grobs = lapply(
  list(f, f2, f3),
  set_panel_size,
  width = unit(2, "in"),
  height = unit(2, "in")
), ncol=3)
```

The legend for the 3rd plot (the `germ_count` plot) ends up as big as the plot itself (and much larger than when f3 is plotted by itself). Further when I save the file using:

```
ggsave(filename = dumb.tif, plot = b, width = 7.25, height = 4 )
```

The plots end up overlapping in a way that does not look at all like they do in the RStudio plot window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, your legend size is determined by the point size from `geom_count`, and these point sizes are absolute. Thus, with a small (2" plot), your legend is going to be quite big.  You can address this by adjusting `max_size` in `scale_size_area`, or just making your plot larger so as to make the relative plot size smaller.

Second, `set_panel_size` sets the *panel* (plot area) sizes, but your actual plots are bigger when you include axes, text, legend, etc. Thus, 2" panels result in overlapping plots when you try to cram them into a 7.25" wide area.  Also `f3`, with a 2" panel, will be wider because it includes a legend.  But your `grid.arrange` call defaults to making all the plots the same width when you use ncol=3.  You need to use `widths` to make the columns different widths.

Putting it all together:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid.extra)
library(egg)

f <- ggplot(mpg, aes(drv, cty)) + geom_boxplot()

f2 <- ggplot(mpg, aes(drv, hwy)) + geom_boxplot()

f3 <- ggplot(mpg, aes(drv, class)) + 
    geom_count() + scale_size_area(max_size = 15)

b <- grid.arrange(grobs = lapply(
    list(f, f2, f3),
    set_panel_size,
    width = unit(3, "in"),
    height = unit(3, "in")
), widths =c(2,2,3), ncol=3)

ggsave(filename = "dumb.png", plot = b, width = 12, height = 4)
```

[image]

Comment: If you really want the legend to be a different absolute size than the points in the plot, you can use `cowplot::get_legend` to grab it and manage it as a separate plot object.  Example here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cowplot/vignettes/shared_legends.html

Comment: Thanks! I choose this answer as it provides enough info to be more general, but @baptiste 's suggestions will work as well. Thanks to both of you

Answer (score 2):

`egg::ggarrange()` currently has issues with widths and heights (oversight, I only tested the case of relative widths/heights and grid units always trick me one way or another). With the dev version you can do,

```
library(egg)
g <- ggarrange(f, f2, f3, nrow=1, 
               widths = rep(unit(2,"in"), 3), 
               heights = unit(2,"in"))

margin <- unit(1,"line")
ggsave('dumb.pdf', plot=g, 
       width = grid::convertWidth(sum(g$widths) + margin, 
                                  unitTo = "in", valueOnly = TRUE),
       height = grid::convertHeight(sum(g$heights) + margin,  
                                    unitTo = "in", valueOnly = TRUE))
```

[image]

The size of the legend is absolute; that's a design choice in ggplot2. You can tweak some parameters in the theme to make the spacing and some margins smaller.

Answer (score -1):

try it this way:

`combined_plot <- arrangeGrob(p1, p2, p3,
     widths = c(2,2,3),
     heights = c(2,2,2),
     ncol = 3)`

`ggsave(filename = combined.png, plot = combined_plot, width = 7.25, height = 4 )`

`arrange.grob()` doesn't do any object assignment. `arrangeGrob()` does, so you can `ggsave()` the output object. No need for `lapply()`. `widths` are given as a vector rather than an overall width. Think of them as a set of proportional widths. Overall plot width/height can be set using `ggsave()`.

Comment: i) grid.arrange not arrange.grob; ii) grid.arrange() does return an object; iii) your code produces a 3x3 layout with 2 empty rows; iv) widths can be absolute.